# Slow relinking database in multi-user situation

Tags: performance, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

We have an access application (split into frontend and backend) that uses the following code to relink tables:

```
Private Function ReconnectTables() As Boolean
On Error Resume Next

    Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
    Dim dbs As DAO.Database
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strConnect As String

    Set dbs = CurrentDb
    strConnect = "\\dfs\prd\departmentX\DepartmentalApplicationX_be.accdb"
    For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
        If tdf.Connect <> "" Then
            tdf.Connect = ";DATABASE=" & strConnect
            tdf.RefreshLink
        End If
    Next

    Set dbs = Nothing
    If Err.Number = 0 Then ReconnectTables = True

End Function
```

This works fine when used by a single user, but *hangs (takes approx. 5 minutes )* as soon as a second user tries to access this.

Is there any way I can avoid this? It looks as if I have two options:

1. Improve performance of relinking, if possible. ***How would this be done?***
2. Completely avoid relinking tables as soon as the application is release to production. I am not sure if that’s advisable at all ? If I stop relinking tables each time, would it still be ***possible to detect the need to relink somehow***?

Thanks for sharing your wisdom !

Comment: Perhaps If Instr(tdf.Connect,strConnect) = 0 Then, for live files, I generally just check if the connection is valid. I usually store the last connection in a table.

Comment: Set strConnect = ";DATABASE=\\dfs\prd\departmentX\DepartmentalApplicationX_be.accdb", then you can try if this `IF tdf.Connect <> "" <and tdf.Connect <>strConnect` helps.

Comment: Hey @DocBrown you seem to have a typo, you should not SET a string.

Comment: Yes ! Thanks! Seems to work like a charm. I expanded @Remou 's suggestion to _If InStr(tdf.Connect, strConnect) = 0 And InStr(tdf.Connect, ";DATABASE=" & strConnect) = 0 Then_

Comment: I also like the idea the keep the connection in a table.. should be handy to promote the fe app from dev env > staging > production

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Set dbs = CurrentDb
strConnect = ";DATABASE=\\dfs\prd\departmentX\DepartmentalApplicationX_be.accdb"
For Each tdf In dbs.TableDefs
    If tdf.Connect <> "" and tdf.Connect<> strConnect Then
        tdf.Connect = strConnect
        tdf.RefreshLink
    End If
Next
```

So the reconnect should only happen if necessary.